# Unable to load library "libjnidispatch.so"

Tags: java, jna, unsatisfiedlinkerror, wind-river-workbench

While running my software in the Wind River OS, I'mm getting the below exception. Internally I'm using JNA Library which is throwing this exception.

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-33" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna-3506402/jna3961384745178924050.tmp: /tmp/jna-3506402/jna3961384745178924050.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object.

    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:851)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:826)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:140)
    at com.pty4j.unix.linux.OSFacadeImpl.<clinit>(OSFacadeImpl.java:95)
    at com.pty4j.unix.PtyHelpers.<clinit>(PtyHelpers.java:212)
    at com.pty4j.unix.Pty.ptyMasterOpen(Pty.java:142)
    at com.pty4j.unix.Pty.openMaster(Pty.java:194)
    at com.pty4j.unix.Pty.<init>(Pty.java:57)
    at com.pty4j.PtyProcess.exec(PtyProcess.java:62)
    at com.pty4j.PtyProcess.exec(PtyProcess.java:54)
```

I've tried mounting the /tmp with exec & noexec. But still no help from that.

In normal Ubuntu, Red Hat, It's working as expected and only on Wind River it's throwing this error.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ramesh G.

Comment: Does the architecture for the native jnidispatch library match that of the WindRiver system?

Comment: Yes, I did see it as some compatibility problems.

Comment: Moreover, Windriver OS is not able to load & operate external things since the OS image was created with high secured mode. While relaxing the security aspect, I'm able to do this, which is not recommended one.